# Implementing a Trie in Python - follow-up

Tags: python, python-3.x, trie

This is a follow-up of [Wikipedia Trie pseudocode in Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106351/wikipedia-trie-pseudocode-in-python)

---

**Code quality improvements**

- `find` has been fixed and a regression test ("bana" vs "banana") has been added so that it will never again be broken that way.
- Used ordinary instance methods when sensible (previous code suffered from staticmethods overuse).
- Significant simplification from the use of Python `defaultdict`
- Operator overloading to provide easy membership test and printing (`__repr__`, `__contains__`)
- Removed the `value` argument as I saw no use for it.
- Minor doc-style language adjustments.
- The printing is not used in testing anymore, as it should not be, because it is arbitrary (as Python's `dict`s are)

**Functionality improvements**

- The printing is now as it should be, not reversed.
- There is no more a weird `inspect` method, you can simply `print` the trie.

---

**Example output**

A trie from the words `('banning', 'banned', 'banana', 'bad', 'cooking', 'cought', 'count')` is printed as:

> ```
> c 
>  o 
>   o 
>    k 
>     i 
>      n 
>       g 
>        # 
>   u 
>    g 
>     h 
>      t 
>       # 
>    n 
>     t 
>      # 
> b 
>  a 
>   n 
>    a 
>     n 
>      a 
>       # 
>    n 
>     i 
>      n 
>       g 
>        # 
>     e 
>      d 
>       # 
>   d 
>    #
> ```

`#` signals the end of a word.

---

**The code**

```
import collections
import doctest

class Trie:
    """
    Implements a Trie (also known as 'digital tree',  'radix tree' or 'prefix tree').

    Where common starting letters of many words are stored just once.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.child = collections.defaultdict(Trie)

    def insert(self, string):
        """
        Add a given string to the trie, modifying it **in place**.

        >>> t = Trie()
        >>> t.insert('hello')
        >>> t.insert('hi')
        >>> list(sorted(t.child.keys()))
        ['h']
        >>> first_node = t.child['h']
        >>> list(sorted(first_node.child.keys()))
        ['e', 'i']

        As you can see, the same `h` was written only once,
        and it is connected with both `i` and `e`.
        """
        node = self
        for char in string:
            node = node.child[char]
        node = node.child[None]


    def __contains__(self, word):
        """
        >>> t = Trie()
        >>> t.insert('example')
        >>> 'example' in t
        True
        >>> 'exemplum' in t
        False
        >>> t.insert('bana')
        >>> 'banana' in t
        False
        >>> t.insert('banning')
        >>> t.insert('banned')
        """
        trie = self

        for char in word:
            if char in trie.child:
                trie = trie.child[char]
            else:
                return False

        return True

    def __str__(self, depth = 0):
        """
        Shows a nicely formatted and indented Trie.

        Cannot be tested as equivalent representations
        are arbitrarly chosen from (`dict`s are not ordered).
        """
        s = []
        for i in self.child:
            s.append( '{}{} {}'.format(
                ' ' * depth, i or '#', '\n' + self.child[i].__str__(depth + 1)))
        return ''.join(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doctest.testmod()
    trie = Trie()
    for word in ('banning', 'banned', 'banana', 'bad', 'cooking', 'cought', 'count'):
        trie.insert(word)
    print(trie)
```

Comment: It seems to me that `t = Trie(); t.insert('banana'); 'bana' in t` would return `True`. Is this really the desired behavior?

Comment: @Jaime I think it should be correct, as banana contains bana, so adding banana you are implicitly adding `b` - `ba` - `ban` - `bana` - `banan`, it is called `prefix tree` for this reason

Comment: I think having all the prefixes show up as 'included' is actually an undesired result of removing the `value` - with it, you could easily have a special sentinel value that isn't normally available to clients that says "this is not an end node of any word in the trie". This would be necessary if you allowed *removing* items from the trie, because without knowing which words have been explicitly added, you can't tell whether `trie.remove('banana')` should also remove `'bana'`.

Comment: @Ivc ok, fixed.

Comment: Is it intended that you never validate whether or not `insert` has actually changed anything? Nothing different happens whether I'm adding a new value or not.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan what do you mean by _validate_?  I have tests for it

Comment: I mean in terms of UI. The user has no idea whether `insert` has actually done anything after they called it unless they `print t` before and after. But does that matter to you?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan in Unix silence means success.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan if you think about it, when I call `with open("foo.txt", "w+") as f: f.write("example")`  there is no message printed, no pop-up, no flashing light telling me that the file has really been written.

Comment: One very important thing! the `Trie` is an ordered data structure hence the **children should be ordered**.

Comment: @CodeYogi I think a correcness bug (or misunderstanding of requirements) should be an answeerr

Answer (score 1):

You could easily extent `__init__` to take a list of strings to add to your `Trie` from the get go.

```
def __init__(self, *args):
    self.child = collections.defaultdict(Trie)
    for arg in args:
        self.insert(arg)
```

Now you could pass an arbitrary number of strings to `Trie` and they'll all be added in initialisation.

Also, if you wanted to you could still make the string representations equivalent by sorting the list before you return it.

```
def __str__(self, depth = 0):
    s = []
    for i in self.child:
        s.append( '{}{} {}'.format(
            ' ' * depth, i or '#', '\n' + self.child[i].__str__(depth + 1)))
    s.sort()
    return ''.join(s)
```

If you're concerned with running time, you can make it flaggable and off by default. Speaking of defaults, you should use `depth=0` (no spaces, [PEP8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id28)) as that's the commonly accepted syntax.

Comment: I was thinking about writing a method, `from_strings` that would generate a Trie from a list of strings, is giving `__init__` more power better than that?

Comment: About performance, printing is by far slower than sorting, so I see no performance issues with  sorting (`sorted` seems better than `sort` to me in this instance, but it is subjective)

Comment: @Caridorc Your mileage may vary on what's better. It largely depends on usage I think. If you were thinking about that though, why not allow `insert`  to take `*args`? That way you could do both anyway. Also I mostly used `sort` to make it easier to separate with `if flag: s.sort()`.

Comment: Yes, the sort thing is pretty subjective `''.join(sorted(s) if should_sort else s)` may be considered more or less readable than yours depending on taste. You mean making `insert` capable of inserting arbitrarly many words?

Comment: Yeah. Insert could take *args and just insert every word that's passed.

Comment: I feel like giving more power to `__init__` is better than giving more power to insert. Also I was thinking about giving it an optional iterable, not indefinitely many args, so that if you have an already existing list you can use it transparently like `set([1,2,3])`

Comment: cool, coincidentally I am also working on implementing [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) in python. Lets see if I finish today will be good to see the comparisons.